# Raspberry Pi connected to Motor Controller- Getting error in code

Tags: rpi.gpio, dc-motor

*Hi, I am getting this code error:

```
*blink.py:25: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.*
GPIO.setup(ENA1,GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/my_python_programs/blink.py", line 27, in <module>
GPIO.output(IN1,GPIO.LOW)
RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT*
```

It is in reference to this code I made to control a motor controller from the raspberry pi. Here is my code. I am wondering what the error is:

```
#ImportedLibraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
#Motor1
PWR= 17
ENA1 = 33
IN1 = 31
IN2 = 29
GND = 39
#Motor2
PWR = 1
ENA2 = 32
IN3 = 18
IN4 = 16
GND = 34
#SetMode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#Motor1
GPIO.setup(ENA1,GPIO.OUT)
PWM1=GPIO.PWM(ENA1,100)
GPIO.output(IN1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2,GPIO.LOW)
#Motor2
GPIO.setup(ENA2,GPIO.OUT)
PWM2=GPIO.PWM(ENA2,100)
GPIO.output(IN3,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN4,GPIO.LOW)
PWM1.start(10)
```

Comment: stop wondering and start reading ... the error message tells you what the error is

Comment: A hint is `GPIO.setup(ENA1,GPIO.OUT)` defines ENA1 as a output, whereis the rest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reads

`RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT*`

Notice how for the `ENA1` pin you make a call to `GPIO.setup()` but don't do so for the other pins you are using. You need to set the mode of a pin (to output, in this case) before you attempt to use it.

So you might try something like this:

```py
#ImportedLibraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
#Motor1
PWR= 17
ENA1 = 33
IN1 = 31
IN2 = 29
GND = 39
#Motor2
PWR = 1
ENA2 = 32
IN3 = 18
IN4 = 16
GND = 34
#SetMode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#Motor1
GPIO.setup(ENA1,GPIO.OUT)
PWM1=GPIO.PWM(ENA1,100)

# setup pins before using them
GPIO.setup(IN1, GPIO.OUT) # <-------------
GPIO.output(IN1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(IN2, GPIO.OUT) # <-------------
GPIO.output(IN2,GPIO.LOW)
#Motor2
GPIO.setup(ENA2,GPIO.OUT)
PWM2=GPIO.PWM(ENA2,100)
GPIO.setup(IN3, GPIO.OUT) # <-------------
GPIO.output(IN3,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(IN4, GPIO.OUT) # <-------------
GPIO.output(IN4,GPIO.LOW)
PWM1.start(10)
```

The other warning that's given:

```
*blink.py:25: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.*
```

is from not releasing the pins after the script ends, so you should end the script with `GPIO.cleanup()` (see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/ )